# Javascript Class Constructor Not Defined

Tags: javascript

I really have no idea how Javascript works. I am used to OOP languages. I have two javascript files, and I want to make a person object. I'm running Main.js as a node file.

Main.js

```
var p = require('./Person.js')
var person = new Person();
```

Person.js

```
exports = function Person ()
{
    console.log("hello")
}
```

I've tried many different things, but it always says Person is not defined.

```
node Main
```

ReferenceError: Person is not defined.

Comment: You're importing the `Person` code's exports as the value of variable `p`, so it should be `var person = new p();`

Comment: After implementing your suggestions I still have the error "TypeError: Person is not a function" at require line.

Comment: Does `Person.js` *really* look *exactly* like what you've posted here?

Comment: Oh wait a sec - it should be `module.exports = ...` not just `exports`. (I think.)

Answer (score 3):

Your issue lies within these lines of code:

```
var p = require('./Person.js');
var person = new Person();
```

`p` holds the module from `Person.js`, so you should create your new `Person` like so:

```
var person = new p();
```

Or (what I recommend for the sake of clarity) change `p` to `Person`:

```
var Person = require('./Person.js');
var myPerson = new Person();
```

Also make sure you use `module.exports` instead of just `exports` here:

```
module.exports = function Person ()
{
    console.log("hello")
}
```

Comment: After implementing your suggestions I still have the error "TypeError: Person is not a function" at require line.

Comment: @Jim The path to your person file might be incorrect - have you checked that?

Comment: All files are in the same folder.

Comment: @Jim instead of `exports = function Person () ...` try `module.exports = function Person () ...`

Comment: @Jim glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

What you mean to do is probably

```
var Person = require('./Person.js');
var person = new Person();
```

Comment: After implementing this suggestion I still get the error "TypeError: Person is not a function" at require line.